# Why is the query in ETL via SSIS slow but via a local stored procedure it is fast?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016, ssis, etl

I'm seeing the classic 'runs fast in studio manager but slow in application' problem. Sounds like it might be parameter sniffing. However, my experience with ETL and SSIS is zero.

From the DBA I received the following query and it ends with a ?  instead of a parameter. Here is an obfuscated sample of the query:

```
SELECT 
tablex.x_id, 
tablex.create_ts, 
tablex.update_ts, 
tablex.myStatus, 
tablex.x_type, 
tablex.ami_uploaded, 
tablex.work_id,
tablex_capture_ts,
[column1],
[column2],
[column3],
[column4] 
FROM     sqltable..tablex 
INNER JOIN 
sqltable..tableWork ON tablex.work_id = tableWork.work_id
WHERE  
(tablex.update_ts >= ?)
```

- According to the DBA, the question mark is replaced with a 'time/date' argument that is one hour in the past.
- When I execute this same query locally from a stored procedure,
  passing in a parameter that is one hour in the past,
  it returns in less than a second. (which to me, means it 'can' use the existing index)
- Watching this execute from the ETL, it takes minutes and the
  execution plan shows table scans.
- There is an update_ts index.

The query engine recommends a second update_ts index with several include columns. I'd like to avoid that if possible as it will add memory pressure and I'm not convinced it solves the real issue. Thoughts?

This seems like a case of the query statistics being skewed and when the query engine sniffs the parameter it avoids using the existing index because the estimated number of rows is beyond the threshold.

My questions:

1. How does the **?** in the SSIS query get handled by sql server? I know parameter sniffing is a complex issue. I've been studying this: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html
2. If it is the query engine sniffing the parameter (of one hour in the past) and thinking the estimated number of rows is beyond the tripping point, what do I do to fix this?  The DBA has refused the hint  OPTIMIZE for RECOMPILE as an option and I can't say I disagree. (He has a point regarding the bug history) However, these queries happen ONLY from the ETL on schedule times and perhaps that is reason enough to use the HINT regardless of the potential bug??

Also, this is a long issue I've been struggling with. All of these posts are related to this same issue. What a voyage of discovery:

[Is this an excessively large 'Lock' time and is it indicative of a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287150/is-this-an-excessively-large-lock-time-and-is-it-indicative-of-a-problem)

[SQL Server - Can I surgically remove a bad cached query plan or am I chasing the wrong idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/sql-server-can-i-surgically-remove-a-bad-cached-query-plan-or-am-i-chasing-the)

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

---

This should be the actual execution plan from the local stored procedure version. This version returns within 1 second and exhibits the behavior I WISH the ETL would have:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry4wy6dBO

Now, this is a screen grab of the ETL version that takes minutes to complete. Sorry I cannot provide more details on this particular query:
[image: A bad ETL estimated execution plan]

---

This is a screen grab from a profiler trace done over an hour period. I think this is how the ETL commands are being executed.  I don't yet, know why these all have the same time. I also need to find the prepare as well. Look at those cpu, reads, and duration columns!

[image: Profiler trace of ETL query]

Comment: Upload the query plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and share the link in your question. Not sure why the `OPTION RECOMPILE` would be concern for an ETL query.

Comment: Where is the query used within SSIS? I presume a Data Flow as an OLE DB Source (OLE uses a `?` as an ordinal based parameter placeholder but ODBC also uses the question mark). How are you measuring that the source is the laggard as opposed to any transformations and the destination?

Comment: @billinkc the ? with query was provided by the DBA in an email. When I look at the execution plan on the production database, it does have a @ P1 instead of a ?.  I had forgotten that fact. As for your last sentence - you'll have to help me. All I can do is look from the production database, not the ETL and I don't understand 'transformations' and 'destination' in this context.

Comment: The OLE/ODBC libraries translate their parameter syntax into the target system so while you have ? in the source query, when it hits SQL Server, you'll see it as a "normal" parameterization of @ P1 etc.

Comment: I seem to be stuck. Both the original execution plan and my edited version fail to paste. Can I provide the XML directly?

Comment: To answer my question, you'll need access to the SSIS package. The source query might run blazing fast in both SSMS _and_ the package. It might be that something after the data is extracted from the database, the rest of the operations they are performing are slow. Really pushing my luck on assumptions, they are loading new and changed data from the source db to the destination. They might be using the "OLE DB Command" object for the updates and that fires off singleton queries to update the target table. It's a common pattern and is fine until data volume don't support one-off changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122506/discussion-between-d-k-and-billinkc).

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you executing a stored procedure in SSMS and then executing the code as a query in SSIS, or is it the same stored procedure in both? 
If you're using a query, I think the parameter gets optimized differently if passed in through SSIS than it does running it via a stored procedure.

Comment: @bcm how the ETL is executing this is unknown to me (other than through SSIS). I am simply creating a local stored procedure so I can determine whether the query CAN return quickly. It can. I do understand that the query engine will not pick the same query plan as used for the ETL.  So either this is a query stats skewing problem or 'how' the ETL query is invoked (perhaps?) that keeps the engine from building a good query plan.

Comment: @D-K With the different plans being generated, that would be my assumption. Can you have the DBA change the package to use your new sp, the text would then be something like `EXEC newproc ?`

Comment: @BCM I can try. That would be the last option as the DBA has expressed reluctance to changing anything on the ETL side. I do have a profiler trace for an hour and this is interesting. It seems that the ssisagent does this: `exec sp_execute 1,'2021-04-01 22:00:02.6200000'`  I sorted based on CPU. I think I'll save a screen grab of this. It seems nuts to me.

Comment: Not sure, without having the SSIS plan, but i would take a look at the datatype of the parameter send in ETL. If its always 1 hour past, why not replace it with a dateadd(hour, -1, getutcdate())

Comment: You need to capture the sp_prepare in your trace and check the datatype of your parameters, if you want to use the index you're much more likely to succeed if the parameter datatype matches the column datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue with a query that was called from EntityFramework.
Was fast in SSMS, but slow from application.

It turned out there was an error in mapping of parameters, their type, which caused the query from application to do a scan, due to the query becomming non-SARGable.

After fixing this issue, the query was fast from application.

Comment: Thank you. This has been a pet theory of mine and hearing your account helps. I have a profiler trace and I'm attempting to learn enough about the data that's saved in the trace to see if this theory pans out. So far I'm still behind the learning curve.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and miss on bounty. Life intervened and I wasn't available to handle this. As for the query and issue - slowly being resolved. We've learned that the ETL is indeed the issue. We've also solidified that running a local stored procedure with the same query and passed parameter executes in less than a second.  So - something about how SSIS is executing these same queries remotely - is the issue.  I won't have the keys to that castle for a another period of weeks.  Customers can be slow sometimes. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share some of the findings and success stories related to this long running saga.

It is amazing what SSIS and ETL can do if you spend the time to learn it.

It turns out that OPTION (RECOMPILE) has brute forced the issue and queries that used to take 4 minutes, now take 800 ms.

Also poorly thought out hacks to get data from the source DB outside of the SSIS eco system... Gone!

It pays to have the keys to the castle and spend time learning the system.

Just to give an example of the fun... one of the systems took 18 total minutes (the full ETL) to do a 30 minute window extraction.

Now we can do a 15 minute window and it takes 90 seconds for everything. Extraction Transform and Load!

So the moral of the story?  Spend time learning SSIS. Spend time tuning the system.